# SQL Group by multiple value groups in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

So I have a table with a column that I need to group by certain categories within that column. For example there is 20 codes in the column that goes in one group called Residential and 30 codes that go in Commercial. Is this possible? How would I create groups made out of multiple different values in the same columns?

Comment: Lot more information required: Your data model, your current query, maybe some sample data.

Comment: you could use [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cb89/3) to create your schema

Comment: Is the relation between codes and the set {Residential, Commercial} recorded in your database?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen This is for the company I'm working for so I am nervous to give out sensitive information, but its basically a table of claims that has a column for where the product was manufactured. The places where they were manufactured are in the same category and I need to group the places by category.

Comment: You can always use dummy data (about everybody does that here) and the data model is never that sensitive: It says nothing about what you are doing. So don't be too nervous. Just be creative and follow the stackoverflow guidelines on getting support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT  code_group, COUNT(*)
FROM    (SELECT CASE WHEN code IN ('code1', 'code2', 'etc') THEN 'Residential'
                     WHEN code IN ('code3', 'code4') THEN 'Commercial'
                     ELSE NULL
                END AS code_group
         FROM . . .) t
GROUP BY code_group
```

Comment: Why is the case expression placed in the FROM statement @Mureinik?